# Validation error in checkout page shipping address

Tags: magento2, validation

Here i am change city and zip code value set by jquery

but

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
value: value,
valueUpdate: 'keyup',
hasFocus: focused,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}" name="city" placeholder="" aria-describedby="notice-XJCWJ1B" id="XJCWJ1B">
```

as per code valueUpdate by keyup so how can i update value of city and zip code without enter anything in that field using jquey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just trigger the keyup event so that validation error is not generated

write this code after set value of city and zip code

like this

```
jQuery('#id').trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: can you explain brief how to do this