# jQuery not working in checkout page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am customizing checkout page. I try set value in form field by using Jquery but did not work.

for making test I will try to hide all input elements in checkout page such a simple task but did not work. alert have came but input element dose not hide.

I have get some idea to why its not working from [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105528/validation-error-in-checkout-page-shipping-address). I have set jquery trigger before and after set value but nothing work.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){

       $(window).load(function(){

       //$("input").trigger('keyup');
       $("input").hide();
       $("input").trigger('keyup');
       alert("hiwq");

    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after setting time delay my problem got solved.I think the input element not get load completely that is why its not found out input element to hide.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){
  // put your code here if you want it in document.ready     
  });

 setTimeout(function(){

   $(window).load(function(){

   $("input").trigger('keyup');
   $("input").hide();
   //$("input").trigger('keyup');
   alert("hiwq");

   });

 }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Time delay always won't work as expected. It depends on the loading speed of the page.

Answer (score 2):

> It should be like below

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){
   // put your code here if you want it in document.ready     
  });

$(window).load(function(){

       //$("input").trigger('keyup');
       $("input").hide();
       $("input").trigger('keyup');
       alert("hiwq");

    });

});
```

check [jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: thanks @Minesh Patel, I have already tried but the problem still remain. now also alert get called but the input element did not get hide.

Comment: comment out this line // $("input").trigger('keyup'); and check

Comment: thank god its finally working after setting time delay. I think the input element not get load completely that is why its not found out input element. Thanks @Minesh Patel

Comment: always welcome @BilalUsean