# using jQuery-ui accordion in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1, css, jquery

**I can not figure out how can i add jQuery-ui accordion to the checkout page block that this [sample module](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block/tree/master/SR/AdditionalShippingBlock/view/frontend), what is made by @sohelrana09, creates?**

.../web/template/checkout/shipping/additional-block.html

```
<div data-bind="visible: canVisibleBlock">
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div><p>Mauris mauris ante</p></div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div><p>Sed non urna.</p></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        require([
            'jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function ($, accordion) {
      $(document).ready(function(){//
  });
setTimeout(function(){
$(window).load(function(){ 
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
    });}, 2000);
});    
    </script>
</div>
```

Reading Magento 2 documentation i know that magento 2 does not contain jQuery ui styles locally. Because of that i created custom css where i dropped accordion styling .css fail content. I added stylesheet to checkout_index_index.xml file head section.

I can not use `require(['jQuery','tabs']..` in script section of html file because it gets the css file though the jQuery page url that does not use https. I also have found this [magento.stackexchange post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111564/jquery-not-working-in-checkout-page-magento-2) but don't know if and how it would help me.

What i added to .../frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file:

```
<head>
    <css src="SR_AdditionalShippingBlock::css/accordion.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working solution:

```
<div data-bind="visible: canVisibleBlock, mageInit: {'accordion':{'openedState': 'active', 'collapsible': true, 'active': [1,4], 'multipleCollapsible': true}} ">
    <div data-role="collapsible"  >
        <div data-role="title">Show hidden</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            The Magento collapsible widget converts a header/content pair into an accordion, where the content is collapsed or expanded on the header click.
            Unlike the accordion widget is that collapsible is initialized for one title/content pair, while accordion can be initialized for a set of title/contents pairs.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible"  >
        <div data-role="title">Show hidden</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            The Magento collapsible widget converts a header/content pair into an accordion, where the content is collapsed or expanded on the header click.
            Unlike the accordion widget is that collapsible is initialized for one title/content pair, while accordion can be initialized for a set of title/contents pairs.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

PS: I don't know exactly what **mageInit** does and have not found anything about it when i searched. Probably it is `data-mage-init`.

Comment: This method works. I tried to replace `mageInit` with `data-mage-mage-init` attribute but that didn't work. Where did you find this piece of code?

Comment: Interesting, I see it's used throughout the core, anywhere that's bound to a Magento_Ui component in either `phtml` or `html` files.  There is documentation for it now...
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#mageinit