# Magento 2 trim checkout fields

Tags: magento2, checkout

I noticed that lots of people put in a space after their email address (autocomplete) i.e. " test@test.com "
I use to use this code in M1:

`$(':input').change(function() { $(this).val($(this).val().trim()); });`

and it was working for all fields.

Is there a way to do this in M2?

Answer (score 0):

To use your jQuery in Magento 2.x you can use the below format jQuery code:

**Update Code:**

`app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function(jQuery){
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function ($) {

                alert('Trigger');
                console.log("Trigger");

                $(':input').change(function() {
                    alert("'"+$(this).val().trim()+"'");
                    $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
                });
            });

        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

**Previous Code:**

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){
      // put your code here if you want it in document.ready
      $(':input').change(function() { $(this).val($(this).val().trim()); });
  });

 setTimeout(function(){

   $(window).load(function(){
       // Your code here
       console.log("bla bla");

   });

 }, 2000);

});
```

Hope this will help you to achieve your requirements. Good Luck.

Ref: [jQuery not working in checkout page - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111564/jquery-not-working-in-checkout-page-magento-2)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. Not even "bla bla" test
Magento 2.4.0

Comment: @AlexI.please check the Update Code, it's working on my Magento 2.4.1, hope it will work on your end.